# Library of functions without classes

Tags: c++

How might one setup a library of functions for use by importing a file. I know you can make a class that is just static variables but there should be a way to do it without classes. What I've tried is this:

lib.h:

```
  1 #include <cstdio>
  2 
  3 namespace el {
  4 
  5 int add(int a, int b);
  6 
  7 }
```

lib.cpp:

```
  1 #include <cstdio>
  2 #include "lib.h"
  3 
  4 using namespace std;
  5 using namespace el;
  6 
  7 int add(int a, int b) {
  8         return a + b;
  9 }
```

main.cpp:

```
  1 #include <cstdio>
  2 #include "lib.h"
  3 
  4 using namespace std;
  5 using namespace el;
  6 
  7 int main() {
  8         printf("%d\n", add(1, 2));
  9 
 10         return 0;
 11 }
```

I am not sure what is wrong with this implementation but what I get is an `Undefined symbols for architecture` error on the add function.

Comment: How did you compile and link it? And please do not post line numbers which make it impossible to compile.

Comment: I tried two ways. Once just with g++ and once linking each file with CMake. Same result both ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put a function definition into a namespace you need:

```
namespace e1 {
     int add(int a, int b) {
         return a + b;
     }
}
```

Comment: Really? You don't need to do this kind of definition for classes.

Comment: @DSchana Yes, you do.

Comment: Why doesn't my attempt work similar to prototype functions?